# Query to show exceptions SQL sales orders

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting, sql-server-2016

I am writing a query to show sales order line items that did not make it onto a blanket order. My base query shows the conditions I am looking for but I believe I need to make this a sub query to get where I need to be. I want to show all results where a given Itemid has a Ordertype of 'R' but does not also have an Ordertype of 'S' and also has QTYORDERED > '0' for every entry in the table. Below query and result is for one specific order that shows the exception I want to report on.

Here is my base query:

```
SELECT h.ORDERTYPE
    ,d.itemid
    ,d.ordernumber
    ,d.HOST_ORIG_QTYORDERED
    ,d.QTYORDERED
    ,d.QTYSHIPPED
    ,d.QTYLOADED
    ,d.qtypicked
    ,d.BLANKET_QTY_RELEASED
    ,d.BLANKET_QTY_RELEASED_SHIPPED
FROM asctrac.dbo.ordrhdr h
INNER JOIN asctrac.dbo.ordrdet d
    ON d.ORDERNUMBER = h.ORDERNUMBER
WHERE h.CUSTPONUM = '69nsk13e'
ORDER BY h.ORDERTYPE
```

[image: Sample data]

Sample data:

```
+-----------+----------+-----------------+----------------------+------------+------------+-----------+-----------+----------------------+------------------------------+
| ORDERTYPE |  itemid  |   ordernumber   | HOST_ORIG_QTYORDERED | QTYORDERED | QTYSHIPPED | QTYLOADED | qtypicked | BLANKET_QTY_RELEASED | BLANKET_QTY_RELEASED_SHIPPED |
+-----------+----------+-----------------+----------------------+------------+------------+-----------+-----------+----------------------+------------------------------+
| R         | 0645182  | OR2219555.2     |            4.0000000 |     4.0000 |     0.0000 |    0.0000 |    0.0000 | 4.0000000            | 4.0000000                    |
| R         | 999992PK | OR2219555.2     |          140.0000000 |   140.0000 |     0.0000 |    0.0000 |    0.0000 | 140.0000000          | 140.0000000                  |
| R         | 0672411  | OR2219555.2     |            1.0000000 |     1.0000 |     0.0000 |    0.0000 |    0.0000 | 1.0000000            | 1.0000000                    |
| R         | 1180286  | OR2219555.2     |            1.0000000 |     1.0000 |     0.0000 |    0.0000 |    0.0000 | 1.0000000            | 1.0000000                    |
| R         | 0030658  | OR2219555.2     |            1.0000000 |     1.0000 |     0.0000 |    0.0000 |    0.0000 | 1.0000000            | 1.0000000                    |
| R         | 0030657  | OR2219555.2     |            1.0000000 |     1.0000 |     0.0000 |    0.0000 |    0.0000 | 1.0000000            | NULL                         |
| R         | 0614536  | OR2219555.2     |            1.0000000 |     0.0000 |     0.0000 |    0.0000 |    0.0000 | NULL                 | NULL                         |
| S         | 0645182  | OR2219555.2-001 |            4.0000000 |     4.0000 |     4.0000 |    4.0000 |    4.0000 | NULL                 | NULL                         |
| S         | 999992PK | OR2219555.2-001 |          140.0000000 |   140.0000 |   140.0000 |  140.0000 |  140.0000 | NULL                 | NULL                         |
| S         | 0672411  | OR2219555.2-001 |            1.0000000 |     1.0000 |     1.0000 |    1.0000 |    1.0000 | NULL                 | NULL                         |
| S         | 1180286  | OR2219555.2-001 |            1.0000000 |     1.0000 |     1.0000 |    1.0000 |    1.0000 | NULL                 | NULL                         |
| S         | 0030658  | OR2219555.2-002 |            1.0000000 |     1.0000 |     1.0000 |    0.0000 |    1.0000 | NULL                 | NULL                         |
+-----------+----------+-----------------+----------------------+------------+------------+-----------+-----------+----------------------+------------------------------+
```

Desired result for this example:

```
+-----------+---------+-------------+----------------------+------------+------------+-----------+-----------+----------------------+------------------------------+
| ORDERTYPE | itemid  | ordernumber | HOST_ORIG_QTYORDERED | QTYORDERED | QTYSHIPPED | QTYLOADED | qtypicked | BLANKET_QTY_RELEASED | BLANKET_QTY_RELEASED_SHIPPED |
+-----------+---------+-------------+----------------------+------------+------------+-----------+-----------+----------------------+------------------------------+
| R         | 0030657 | OR2219555.2 |            1.0000000 |     1.0000 |     0.0000 |    0.0000 |    0.0000 |            1.0000000 | NULL                         |
+-----------+---------+-------------+----------------------+------------+------------+-----------+-----------+----------------------+------------------------------+

I believe I figured out a reasonable way to do get the desired result:
```

```
SELECT h.ORDERTYPE
    ,h.CUSTPONUM
    ,d.itemid
    ,d.ordernumber
    ,d.HOST_ORIG_QTYORDERED
    ,d.QTYORDERED
    ,d.QTYSHIPPED
    ,d.QTYLOADED
    ,d.qtypicked
    ,d.BLANKET_QTY_RELEASED
    ,d.BLANKET_QTY_RELEASED_SHIPPED
FROM asctrac.dbo.ordrhdr h with (nolock)
INNER JOIN asctrac.dbo.ordrdet d
    ON d.ORDERNUMBER = h.ORDERNUMBER
WHERE exists (select distinct CUSTPONUM 
              from asctrac.dbo.ordrhdr ssh with (nolock)
              Where ssh.ORDERTYPE = 'S'
              and ssh.custponum = h.CUSTPONUM)
and h.ORDERTYPE = 'R'
and d.QTYORDERED > '0'
and not exists (SELECT 1
            FROM asctrac.dbo.ordrhdr sh with (nolock)
            INNER JOIN asctrac.dbo.ordrdet sd
                ON sd.ORDERNUMBER = sh.ORDERNUMBER
            WHERE sh.ORDERTYPE = 'S'
            and sh.CUSTPONUM = h.CUSTPONUM
            and sd.itemid = d.ITEMID)
```

Comment: Add your database tag. Add sample data and expected results as text not as image.

Comment: I added the results as text but the formatting looks terrible. I apologize I am new here and am just looking for help.

Comment: Hi @MarkSlagle , what is your database? Oralce ? MySQL ? Or something else ?

Comment: It is a SQL database.

Comment: No it is not, SQL is just a language. I can see your sql tag.

Comment: Again I apologize for being ignorant, I have a 2016 Microsoft SQL server so I have always assumed that I have a SQL database.

Comment: Thanks @Eric Brandt for the formatting help!

Comment: Hi @MarkSlagle , you are doing great. Now one more thing: add the results you expect to get from this sample data.

Comment: Sure thing. The tools I used are all referenced in this pretty old but very good blog post; [How to post a T-SQL question on a public forum](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/). Also, regarding the database type, there's an explanation here: [Why should I “tag my RDBMS”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Comment: Results added and it is legible thanks to @Eric Brandt

Comment: Solution added, thanks guys.

Comment: Mark, you posted a query, but is there a problem? Are you not getting results you are expecting? Also just to clear up the SQL question, SQL itself is a language, while the software to store and manage data are called DBMS(database management system) SQL Server, Oracle, PostgreSQL, MySQL are all examples of DBMS software that store data and interpret SQL language statements to process data. Each DBMS also has slight SQL language dialect differences, which is why it important to tag your question with with DBMS you are using.